# Can I flatten out an object hierarchy in the Locals window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the Locals window, or when hovering over an object, I'd like to see all the properties of the object at the same level in the hierarchy.

I get this kind of thing:

```
[-] sub
    [-] base
        BaseId
    SubId
```

But I'd like to see this kind of thing:

```
[-] sub
    BaseId
    SubId
```

I'd like this to be the way *all* classes are displayed.

It's different with IntelliSense, where all the properties and methods are presented at the same level.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and C#, but this applies to older VS releases and other languages.

Comment: You could do this with a simple extension method, would that me acceptable?

Comment: That would work if there were just a few classes I'd like to see flattened-out.  But in fact I'd like to see everything flattened-out.

Comment: AFAIK VS doesn't allow this out-of-the-box, you could do it with the Watch or Immediate windows with a simple extension using Reflection.

Comment: Debug visualizers let you customize the view of single values. I seem to recall there being a more general mechanism, though I can't now recall the name. That's how arrays and lists, for example, have a special display in Intellisense and the locals window.

Comment: Not really what you are looking for I don't think. BUT, if these are your own classes you can leverage the DebuggerDisplay attribute to get a custom formatted string to show up in the watch window http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx

Comment: It defeats the point of the hierarchy, a simple work around is to use the Immediate Window combined with Intellisense, thats what I do

Comment: Thanks Jeremy!  That's probably the best solution for my purposes.  And thanks to all for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx

You'll probably end up needing to use the type proxies, since they provide the most flexibility. It appears that you may be able to apply them to types you did not create.

Comment: Thanks Siride.  This seems a nice solution for individual classes. I was looking for something more general, like Jeremy Thompson's solution.

Comment: @OutstandingBill I don't see Jeremy Thompson's solution; he may have deleted it.

Comment: it's the 6th comment under the original question